# How can I fold #ifdef/#ifndef blocks in Emacs?

Tags: c, emacs

I want to hide blocks of #ifdef and #ifndef blocks in C.  Looks like I'd either need to use Folding mode or the Outline minor mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*hide-ifdef-mode* should do something like that. I have not used it myself though, but turn it on and read it's description with the commands below. It should be included with emacs.

```
M-x hide-ifdef-mode
C-h m
```

Comment: Also, that to take effect requires `Alt-x hide-ifdefs` after activating the mode (or use the **Hide-Ifdef** menu which is added as a main menu after activating).

Answer (score 1):

You can use folding-mode from Cedet